# Meteor fails in production mode but runs on local development server

Tags: meteor, centos, meteor-up

The OS is Centos 6.2 on an intel X86_64 architecture.  Node version is 4.0.0.  I created the starter project and tried building and running it using

```
meteor
```

as well as

```
meteor run
```

for running in a local development server and

```
meteor run --production
```

for emulating production mode.  Only the "meteor run" command worked.  Both the plain "meteor" and "meteor run --production" gave the following error:

> => Started proxy.
>   W20151229-23:28:35.043(0)? (STDERR)
>   W20151229-23:28:35.046(0)? (STDERR)
>   W20151229-23:28:35.047(0)? (STDERR) #
>   W20151229-23:28:35.047(0)? (STDERR) # Fatal error in ../deps/v8/src/platform-linux.cc, line 776
>   W20151229-23:28:35.048(0)? (STDERR) # CHECK_EQ(0, result) failed
>   W20151229-23:28:35.048(0)? (STDERR) #   Expected: 0
>   W20151229-23:28:35.048(0)? (STDERR) #   Found: 11
>   W20151229-23:28:35.049(0)? (STDERR) #
>   W20151229-23:28:35.049(0)? (STDERR)
>   => Exited from signal: SIGTRAP

I have searched for answers and one suggestion is to use meteor-up, but centos is not supported.  I'd love to able to use Meteor for my next project, but can't until I can get a production version running on this server.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Some more information: line 776 in platform-linux.cc is caused by an error return from Thread::DeleteLocalThreadKey.  When I ran "sudo meteor", the code worked.  Am I perhaps missing some permission on the non super user account?